# PHP PDO - select from where (get value from input field)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I want to run query to get data from mysql with php pdo.

Query must be like this: `SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje where ID_akt = (I need to get value from html with ajax)...`

So first I have a mysql data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `akt_djubrenje` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_akt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hemija` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `kol` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jmere` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

also I have an input field HTML with value:

```
<input id="akt_djubrenje" name="akt_djubrenje" type="text" placeholder="1" value="1" class="form-control input-md">
```

How I need to fetch data from mysql where `ID_akt = $_POST['akt_djubrenje']`

so I write this php PDO file:

```
try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $statement->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_POST['akt_djubrenje']));

      $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje where ID_akt = :akt_djubrenje"');



      $rows = array();
      $table = array();
      $table['cols'] = array(

        array('label' => 'ID', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'Hemija', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Kolicina', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'Jed.mere', 'type' => 'string')

    );
        foreach($result as $r) {
          $temp = array();
          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['ID']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['hemija']);
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['kol']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['jmere']); 

          $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
```

also I call php file with ajax:

```
          function tabela() {
                var json = $.ajax({
                url: 'getdjubrenje.php', // make this url point to the data file
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false
            }).responseText;


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);


  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('akt_djubrenje'));
  visualization.draw(data, null);
}
```

But I dont get anything?

Can anybody see what can be a problem here and how I can solve it?

also when I run php file I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/agroagro/public_html/getdjubrenje.php on line 18`

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `execute()` command under the query, also you need to use object created with the query

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM akt_djubrenje where ID_akt = :akt_djubrenje");
$result->execute(array(':akt_djubrenje' => $_POST['akt_djubrenje']));
```

From documentation

> - call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables to the parameter markers: bound variables pass their value as input and receive the output value, if any, of their associated parameter markers
> - or pass an array of input-only parameter values

Learn more [**here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: ok, thats fine but again I can;t see anything. Is a problem into jquery ajax code there?

Comment: I do this but now when I run php file I get: ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':akt_djubrenje"' at line 1

Comment: Check my updated answer, i changed quotes in the query, you had an extra double quotes

Comment: ok, lets say that php pdo file is now fine but again I cant see table: http://agroagro.com/aktivnosti1.html (click on add new button and then tab mehanizacija) ...

Comment: That's just fantastic "answer" and fantastic edit. And fantastic upvotes as well

Comment: again I get error: ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':akt_djubrenje' at line 1

Comment: What is the method of your form?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the data to the server script from your ajax call

```
        $('#akt_djubrenje').on('click',function()  {
            var data=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
               url: 'getdjubrenje.php', // make this url point to the data file
               dataType: 'json',
               data:{'akt_djubrenje':data},
               async: false,
               success:function(json){
                   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                   visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('akt_djubrenje'));
                   visualization.draw(data, null);
               }
            });
        });
```

At the server end, call `$_POST['akt_djubrenje']` to retrieve the data passed from the html file.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Again dont work: http://agroagro.com/aktivnosti1.html (click on button add new and then tab mehanizacija ... really dont know what is the problem

Comment: @gmaestro: is the data `akt_djubrenje` being received at your server script successfully ?

Comment: yes I think..... I must call function tabela_djubrenje (); function on button click or not ?

Comment: @gmaestro: yes , you  need to call the function which is holding the above ajax call.

Comment: I call it with: $( "#otvori" ).click(function() {
tabela_djubrenje();
}); but again I cant see anything ... what can be a problem now?

Comment: @gmaestro: I can see that from the code what you have posted that the ajax call is in `function tabela() { }` module and not in `tabela_djubrenje();`, so verify that once.

Comment: I post tabela_djubrenje(); and I call it in console but I get UNDEFINED

Comment: also in my php file I get: ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':akt_djubrenje' at line 1

Comment: I see that the problem is with php file and exactly problem is with how to get value from HTML input...

Comment: @gmaestro: i have corrected the code now, use the code as it is.

Comment: Can you also update php file please, where I need to put $_POST ... ?